# Estimating size of state space

Tags: reference-request, artificial-intelligence, search-algorithms

I have been studying search problems in AI, and I am having some troubles understanding some points in these concepts:

1. **State Space:** "represents the environment of the problem, the set of all states reachable from the initial state."
2. **Search Graph:** "the nodes are states and the arcs between nodes are actions"
3. **Search Trees:** a conversion of the Search Graph to a tree.
4. **Branching Factor:** the maximum number of states we can get by moving from old state to a new state using the successor function.

Specifically, how can I estimate the size of my space? and the branching factor? is there any counting rules that usually help?

I have mainly studied from the book *"Artificial Intelligence A Modern Approach"* and I couldn't find answers to these questions.  Online resources mainly focus on either the 8-puzzle or n-queens problem.

If you could suggest any examples or resources that would be great.

Comment: Please post only one question per post.

Comment: they're kind of interleaving that's why I post all together :)

Comment: You should narrow down your issue then. I can't tell what your problem is. Is it with terminology? With understanding what you read? With analysing algorithms? With designing algorithms?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  This site format doesn't work so well when you have multiple questions in your post or when you ask open-ended questions, so we want you to ask only one question per post and we want you to think about how to formulate a specific, narrowly focused question.   I've edited your question to focus only on your first question.  You can ask the other separately -- feel free to make a new post for each other question (you can find them in the revision history).  Or, you can wait to see if you get an answer to this one before posting another.